Multithread an Expect script in bash
I have a bash script running on RH linux that takes in a list of devices, loops through the list and calls an Expect script to SSH to each device.
#!/bin/bash
while read device
do

 /home/bin/get-device-expect.sh $device

done < /home/files/device_list.txt

The Expect script will SSH to each device, run some commands and dumps the output to a $device.txt file.
With 500 devices, this loop takes a long time.
How can I multi-thread this?
I probably don't want it attempting to log in to 500 devices simultaneously. But perhaps a way to do 20, then the next 20 and so.
A way to specify 'n' devices at a time would be great.

You could run multiple copies of the script, each handling a different portion of the list of devices.

Try xargs -P 20 -L 1 -r get-device-expect.sh < device_list.txt or xargs -a device_list.txt -P 20 -L 1 -r get-device-expect.sh

This one worked beautifully. Thank you. I put it inside a bash script, and added some bells a whistles around it.

Assumptions:

each device from devices_list.txt consists of a single string with no embedded white space

Setup:
$ cat device_list.txt
device_1
device_2
device_3
device_4
device_5
device_6
device_7
device_8
device_9

$ cat get_device.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "input: $@"
sleep 4

One idea would be to use xargs:
cat device_list.txt | xargs -r -P4 -n1 ./get_device.sh

### or

xargs -r -P4 -n1 ./get_device.sh < device_list.txt

Where:

-P4 - run at most 4 copies in parallel
-n1 - each invocation of ./get_device.sh is to receive one argument (aka device) as input; remove -n1 to see what happens if you don't include this limitation

Both of the above generate the following:
input: device_1          # 4 lines of output in quick succession
input: device_2
input: device_3
input: device_4
                         # 4-sec delay
input: device_5          # 4 lines of output in quick succession
input: device_6
input: device_7
input: device_8
                         # 4-sec delay
input: device_9          # only 1 device left so only one instance of get_device.sh is called
                         # 4-sec delay


If you don't have a version xargs with the non-POSIX -P option then you could do something like this which will start 20 background processes and then start the 21st one when one of the first 20 dies, the 22nd when one of the first 21 dies, etc.:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

get-dev-expect() {
    sleep 3
    echo /home/bin/get-device-expect.sh "$@"
}

cnt=0
max=20
while IFS= read -r device; do
    ( get-dev-expect "$device") &
    while (( ++cnt < max )); do
        if IFS= read -r device; then
            ( get-dev-expect "$device") &
        fi
    done

    wait -n
done < device_list

wait


You can run execute several expect cmd in parallel from the main loop and wait for them to finish before launching a new set:
#!/bin/sh

expect_cmd() {
  echo "Expect script running on $1"
  sleep 3 # Simulate some work... 
}

wait_processes() {
   echo Waiting processes: $*
   wait $pid_list
}

# Max number of expect commands running in //
max=5
i=0
pid_list=

while read dev
do
  expect_cmd $dev &
  pid_list="$pid_list $!" 
  i=`expr $i + 1`
  if [ $i -eq $max ]
  then
    wait_processes $pid_list
    # Begin a new set of commands to launch in //
    i=0
    pid_list=
  fi
done < device.txt

# Wait for the remaining commands if the
# total number is not a multiple of $max
if [ -n "$pid_list" ]
then
  wait_processes $pid_list
fi

Execution example with 11 devices in the input file:
./try.sh
Expect script running on dev1
Expect script running on dev2
Expect script running on dev3
Expect script running on dev4
Expect script running on dev5
Waiting processes: 24428 24431 24434 24437 24440
Expect script running on dev6
Expect script running on dev7
Expect script running on dev8
Expect script running on dev9
Expect script running on dev10
Waiting processes: 24447 24450 24453 24456 24459
Expect script running on dev11
Waiting processes: 24464


I've had success with GNU parallel: gnu-parallel
You could do:
mapfile -t devices < device_list.txt
parallel get-device-expect.sh ::: "${devices[@]}"

I believe, by default, it will spawn as many processes as you have CPU cores.
